# Do I have to set hibernate to weblogic?

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic

I am just wondering, do I have to set anything in my weblogic server about the Hibernate?
So my app is using hibernate for the database, and if I want to deploy my app on a weblogic server, it would be all OK (if my app hasn't got any error), or it is not enough just to deploy it, should I set anything about the hibernate to work on weblogic?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need set any thing in web logic server.You just need to add respective libraries and configuration files.But it might be possible that you want to access database via JNDI lookup.There you need to set up JNDI.

Answer (score 1):

You would be fine to use hibernate without configuring WebLogic if you're using the hibernate.cfg.xml to store your configuration.  If you want to use the WebLogic JNDI then you would need to put this configuration within WebLogic.  Please have a read of the hibernate documentation regarding container managed transactions [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-j2ee)

Hibernate can work independently to the application server you choose.

Comment: I guess OP means if he/she has to add Hibernate libraries to the project since Weblogic already packages it, like JBoss.

Comment: It depends how OP wants it configured.  As the libraries are provided they can either use a hibernate.cfg.xml or go the route of using container managed transactions.  As they don't _have_ to use container managed transactions, they should just be able to use a config file and not touch WebLogic.